# Constraints on template types

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference, higher-order-functions

Suppose, I want to implement a generic higher-order `Map` function in C++. `Map` should take a container and a transformation function and return a container of the same type, but possibly with different type of items.

Let's take `vector` for instance:

```
template <typename InT, typename OutT, typename Tr>
vector<OutT> Map(vector<InT> cont, Tr tr)
{
    OutCont out(cont.size());
    auto oit = out.begin();
    for (auto it = cont.cbegin(); it != cont.cend(); ++it, ++ot)
    {
        *oit = tr(*it);
    }
}
```

which I want to use like this:

```
vector<int> v(10);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
auto x = Map(v, [](int x) -> int {return x * 2;});
```

This fails in VC++ 2012, giving me the following error:

```
error C2783: 'std::vector<OutT> Map(std::vector<_Ty>,Tr)' : could not deduce template argument for 'OutT'
```

It seems to me that the compiler has all the necessary information, because I explicitly defined the return type in the lambda. Is there a way around this?

The above example uses `vector`. Is there a way to use a generic type, so that the input and output types are the same? For instance if I have an input container defined as `vector<string>` and the transformation function `tr(string a) -> int`, then my goal is to make the compiler to figure out the output type to be `vector<int>`. Here's the pseudo-code for what I want to achieve:

```
template <typename Cont<InT>, typename Cont<OutT>, typename Tr<InT, OutT>>
Cont<OutT> Map(Cont<InT> cont, Tr<InT, OutT> tr)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but naming your function `map` is a bit confusing, given `std::map`.

Comment: Functional programming `map` == `std::transform`. Iterators are really what allow you to do generic programming over containers in C++ : use them.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to `Map`. Should eliminate the confusion.

Comment: You should use iterators

Comment: @thokra I meant as input/output types, they are easily generalized to fit multiple containers

Comment: I'm aware of `std::transform`, but it is not exactly what I want (or I don't know how to use it the way I want). First `std::transform` works on iterators, second it requires that you initialize the output container in advance. I want to save some typing. But I'm also interested in technical details of implementing such a function.

Comment: @Max: I'm confused. From which function argument is the compiler supposed to deduce `OutT`? You use `OutCont`, which I assume to be a `typedef std::vector<OutT> OutCont`, but the compiler cannot deduce template arguments by inspecting the return type, can it? Would be new to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Btw, you might be able to use `decltype` to specify the output type

Comment: Yeah, that might work.

Comment: @thokra. I thought that I could deduce it from the lambda's return type.

Comment: Either decltype or result_of. As it stands there's no way to deduce the output type from the params. You can probably thank implicit casting for that one.

Comment: @Max: There's a slight bug. You don't increment `oit` - therefore you only store the result of the last element from the input sequence in `oit[0]`. Either do it inside the loop, or add the incrementation in the `for` statement, i.e. `for( ...; ... ; ++it, ++oit)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write something like:

```
template <typename InT, typename Tr>
auto Map(std::vector<InT> cont, Tr tr) -> std::vector<decltype(tr(cont[0]))>
{
    std::vector<decltype(tr(cont[0]))> out(cont.size());
    auto oit = out.begin();
    for (auto it = cont.cbegin(); it != cont.cend(); ++it, ++oit)
    {
        *oit = tr(*it);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Out type is deduced.

[Edit]
For a more generic function with more container:

```
template <template<typename, typename...> class Container, typename InT, typename Tr, typename... Args>
auto Map(const Container<InT, Args...>& cont, Tr tr) -> Container<decltype(tr(cont[0])), Args...>
{
    Container<decltype(tr(cont[0])), Args...> out(cont.size());
    auto oit = out.begin();
    for (auto it = cont.cbegin(); it != cont.cend(); ++it, ++oit)
    {
        *oit = tr(*it);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Notice the `typename...` needed because `std::vector` can also take allocator

Comment: Thank you. That was what I needed. Still there's the question of making this for for a generic type, rather than just for vector.